# How to configure Drools to run with JBOSS?

Tags: java, jboss, drools

I have a java application which is deployed in a jboss 5, and I m using drools in my application. so need some information on what i need to do to get the drools runtime environment in jboss.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can embed drools in your application, that means that you can create a web application add the drools dependencies and just use drools inside that application. There are several architectures and ways of working with drools inside jboss, can you specify a little bit more about what do you want to achieve?
Cheers